# d3 intelliense missing in vue application

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, intellisense

I installed d3 with `yarn add d3`, then imported it with `import * as d3 from 'd3'`, but there is no intellisense for it. Just below that I have moment.js imported and it is working just fine. This is inside a Vue application (no TypeScript).

Comment: Which editor/IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using VSCode.